# How to flash Flipper Zero with custom firmware

Tags: command-line-interface, firmware

I recently just purchased a a Flipper Zero because I thought it was a useful cool toy and tool to have in the times we live in. I’m new to the scene and I would like to know what is the difference between stock and custom fw? Meaning what can’t the flipper do that the custom firmware is allowing.

Lastly, how would I go about flashing the flipper to a custom firmware like RogueMaster?

Answer (score 1):

Custom firmware forks (such as [Unleashed](https://github.com/Eng1n33r/flipperzero-firmware) and [RogueMaster](https://github.com/RogueMaster/flipperzero-firmware-wPlugins) (which is a fork of unleashed)) contain additional features and functionality, such as additional plugins, removal of some regional transmission restrictions (may be illegal in your country, please check your local laws), and smaller tweaks (usually listed in the fork's readme). The firmware forks are just built on top of the stock firmware, so anything that the stock firmware can do, the forks can also do. You may also want to compile your own fork, taking features you like from all of the different forks.

The easiest way to install a custom firmware fork is to:

(I'm using RogueMaster in this example)

1. Download the current release of your fork from the releases tab on their github
2. Extract the zip into "update" folder in your flipper's SD card (either through qFlipper or just by manually connecting your SD to your computer)
3. Connect the SD to the flipper and navigate to the "update" folder using the archive app (down from the flipper desktop)
4. Select your update directory and select the "update" option and click "run in app"
5. Wait a few minutes and your firmware will be updated

OR if you want to compile from source

1. `git clone --recursive <URL TO YOUR FORK>`
2. `cd` into the cloned directory
3. Run `./fbt` to setup the toolchain and compile the firmware
4. Connect your flipper to your computer and open qFlipper
5. Once connected, select "Install from file" and select `<PATH_TO_YOUR_FORK>/dist/f7-C/flipper-z-f7-full-local.dfu`
6. Click install and wait for the process to finish

Note: This is not a guide on how to install region-lock bypassing firmware, just a guide on how to install custom firmware forks. It is your responsibility to follow your local laws and to use your flipper responsibly. Good luck!